# How to get identation width of QTreeView from QStyle

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget, qtreeview, qstyle

I have pre-existing code which has a tree view like appearance but doesn't actually use QTreeView (uses QListWidget with custom paint).

I am tasked to add the indentation between the parent and child objects, but I can't able to find how to get the style default indentation width from QStyle. The program has to run on a variety of os and allow to use custom stylesheets. So it's important to get this option from QStyle.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this in qt sources

have to use QStyle::pixelMetric with QStyle::PM_TreeViewIndentation
inside your widget's procedure

`ident = style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_TreeViewIndentation)`

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).